# Naming string variables which point to files and directories

Tags: naming-conventions

This is the kind of question where if you ask 10 people, you'll get 10 answers, but I'm trying to work out how best to name the following variables:

Variable 1) A string which points to a folder containing some software on the C drive. The variable will contain something like "C:\Program Files\MySoftware".

Variable 2) A string which contains an absolute path to a web.config file within the above folder. For example "C:\Program Files\MySoftware\web.config".

Variable 1 could be called something like "softwarePath", but then if variable 2 was called "webConfigPath", it's not immediately obvious if that variable should contain the complete path to the file, or the path to the folder which the file lives in.

It seems to me that using the word "path" in a variable is a little ambiguous, since it could mean a file or a directory, and I like to make variable names as self-explanatory as possible.

So I'm interested to hear any naming conventions that others might use for the above scenario when referencing absolute paths to files, and absolute paths to directories.

Please note I am not interested in having variables which contain JUST a filename. All variables will contain absolute paths to either a file or a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like it as self-explanatory as possible why not add an additional qualifier?

`webConfigDirPath` and `webConfigFilePath`

Comment: Yes that's good enough to clear up confusion - thanks for your suggestion.